# Realm on Flutter error ‘unable to decrypt after 0 seconds

Tags: mongodb, realm

I used realm base on flutter, I insert data into realm and found error

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::util::DecryptionFailed: Decryption failed: 'unable to decrypt after 0 seconds (retry_count=2, from=iv1 == 0, size=16384)'
* thread #9, name = 'io.flutter.1.ui', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001ddf67160 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`:
->  0x1ddf67160 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1ddf67180               ; <+40>
    0x1ddf67164 <+12>: pacibsp
    0x1ddf67168 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1ddf6716c <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

```
var config = Configuration.local(
  schemas,
  encryptionKey: rawKey,
  path: "$_dbPath/${dbType.name}.realm",
  schemaVersion: odaSchemaVersion,
  shouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded: ,
  shouldCompactCallback: (_forServer ? (totalSize, usedSize) => true : null),
);
```

```
realm.write(() {
  realm.addAll<T>(data, update: true);});
```

please help

Comment: Hello, could you add to your question your code causing this error ?

Comment: `var config = Configuration.local(
     schemas,
     encryptionKey: rawKey,
     path: "$_dbPath/${dbType.name}.realm",
     schemaVersion: odaSchemaVersion,
     shouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded: ,
     shouldCompactCallback: (_forServer ? (totalSize, usedSize) => 
     true : null),
      );
     Realm realm = Realm(config);

   realm.write(() {
   realm.addAll<T>(data, update: true);
   });`
@GregoireDucharme

Comment: Here on SO, code should not be added in comments as it's incredibly hard to read. Code should be added to the question and formatted for readability.

Comment: sorry now i update my post question @Jay

Comment: It appears there's an open ticket related to this issue [Make encrypted Realms cross platform compatible #3499](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/3499)